# VS Code permanently disable bottom panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, panel

VS Code v1.64.0 brought a new side panel and as a result, all my workspaces now open with a big empty bottom panel covering up half the screen. Gets old fast manually closing that repeatedly. Is there a way to permanently disable the bottom panel across workspaces?

[image]

Comment: Check the setting: `Workbench > Panel: Open Maximized` maybe you changed it or try `never`.  Otherwise vscode should remember whether you closed it last time.

Comment: @Mark That was one of the things I tried before posting here. Prob should've mentioned it but it didn't help. With `"workbench.panel.opensMaximized": "never"`, panel still shows up when I open workspaces.

Comment: do the release notes say anything about settings for this new feature

Comment: [Don't think so](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64#_new-side-panel). Have to admit I skimmed, not read carefully.